# Nodejs with C# together in a backend

Tags: c#, node.js

This probably sounds a bit opinion based question, but please bear with me.

We are preparing to create a backend, exposing API.
The backend server needs to handle 100k concurrent connections and latency is a huge concern for us.

Would it be a good idea to host the API endpoints on NodeJS server and then passing over the compute heavy operations to another language (through private APIs) based processes (e.g. C#)?
This way we get the non-blocking IO benefit of Node and also multi-threading and other benefits of matured language ecosystem of C# or Java.

Or is it considered an anti-pattern in NodeJS world?

Comment: You can get "non-blocking IO" just as easily in a C# server using async/await

Comment: `passing over the compute heavy operations to another language` -- be careful with this, as you might accidentally incur performance cost in the marshalling of data between the two languages or APIs (i.e. you're trying to encode/decode JSON on both sides). On the other hand, NodeJS does support [parallel worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) in v10.5

Comment: AFAIU what you are basically describing is [microservices architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) with node.js serving as an endpoint handler microservice for concurrent operations and python as a heavy computation microservice. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan I think you are right in this assumption. Do you see any issue in this approach?

Comment: Nope, not really. Then again go for this approach only if you are sure you aren't able to make use of worker threads and other concepts else you would incur cost on communication like @arthurkay suggested